# Which version of Velocity Template will support map creation

Tags: java, velocity

Am sending map and accessing in velocity template version 1.2 but I tried to create map in vm I couldn't create and getting exception.Please give you guidance.

```
#set($buyerActionStat = {
                            "0":"New",
                            "5":"Response-Acknowledged",
                            "6":"Response-Accepted",
                            "7":"Response-Rejected"                         
                        })
```

**Exception :**

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Lexical error: org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 5, column 25.  Encountered: "{" (123), after : ""
    at org.apache.velocity.Template.process(Template.java:181)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager.getResource(ResourceManager.java:327)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:736)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.getTemplate(RuntimeSingleton.java:355)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.getTemplate(Velocity.java:533)
    at ecnet.rd.core.template.TemplateResolver.<init>(TemplateResolver.java:45)
    at ecnet.rd.core.template.TemplateResolver.getInstance(TemplateResolver.java:34)
    at ecnet.rd.helper.AMECPOHelper.mergePOTemplate(AMECPOHelper.java:71)
```

Comment: what Exception you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the expcetion is caused by velocity versions only.

Use apache `velocity` version `1.6.2` or later versions.

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
```